# Increasing TTL for incoming packages

Tags: package, increment, ttl

I have such a problem. 
I want to build my own home local area network based on Windows 2008 Server. This OS is installed on the machine with two network interfaces (first is connected to Internet, second - to local network). 
I need to increase TTL for each incoming package, because my provider always sets TTL value to 1, so each package is dropped by gateway (it is a computer with server OS). I don't know, how to do this and Google says nothing. **I don't need to set default TTL**, I know, how do this via registry, **I need to increase it for incoming packages**.